# How to output average rating with stars?

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to output the average rating in a number format, but i would like to output it by using the star method as well.

This is my code so far that outputs the average rating by using numbers;

```
<?php

$sql = "
    SELECT round(avg(`rate`),2) AS `average_rate`, count(`rate`) AS `num_of_rating`
    FROM tbl_rating 
    WHERE hotel_id = '$id' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rating = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
?>

<div>
    <h4 style="color: #1478FF; font-size:30px; font-family:  " >    <?php echo $rating['average_rate'];  ?> Avergae rating </h4>
</div>
```

For instance;[Stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AYVw.jpg)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Do you have a star sprite or Icon? The simplest way to display the stars is to add a loop after you output the average rating from 1 to Floor(avg_rate) and then display a half star if the fractional part of the rating is greater than 0.49. I'm an old ColdFusion guy, so don't ask me to write the PHP code for this :)

Comment: @RusselMadere i didn't understand u

Comment: Here are the steps you need to perform. - Calculate the Floor of the average rating (convert it to an integer without rounding). - Loop from 1 to that value. - Each time through the loop, display a star icon. - After the loop, if the remainder of the average rating is greater than 0.499999 display a half star icon.

Comment: @RusselMadere Can you please do the coding part for me? The explanation you gave me is quite complex...

Comment: @amir, I will try. As I stated, I do not know php, so I will be googleing everything.

Comment: @RusselMadere i appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
<?php

$sql = "
    SELECT round(avg(`rate`),2) AS `average_rate`, count(`rate`) AS `num_of_rating`
    FROM tbl_rating 
    WHERE hotel_id = '$id' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rating = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
?>

<div>
    <h4 style="color: #1478FF; font-size:30px; font-family:  " >    <?php echo $rating['average_rate'];  ?> Average rating </h4>
<?php
    $limit = floor($rating['average_rate']);
    $remainder = $rating['average_rate'] % 1.0;

    for( $i = 0; $i<$limit; $i++ ) {
        echo ("<img src=\"\\images\\fullstar.jpg\" />");
    }

    if ($remainder >= 0.5) echo ("<img src=\"\\images\\halfstar.jpg\" />");
?>
</div>
```

I'm not sure this will work. I have no way of testing the code, I'm a C# and ColdFusion developer. This is what a few minutes on Google gave me.

To make this work, you need images of a full star called fullstar.jpg and of a half start called halfstar.jpg. They both need to be in a folder names images in your project root.

Comment: What is the rating that should be displayed? Check the value of $limit. if it is not the correct number, let me know.

Comment: It's working but it's not displaying the half star. IF its 4 stars its working, but if it's like 3.52 it just displays 3 stars...

Comment: @amir, the key to solving that problem is to look at the value of $remainder and make sure it is calculating properly you could replace the line with $remainder = $rating['average_rate'] - $limit;

Comment: Okay its working fine now. However, i have one more question. Is it possible to display the rest of the stars but empty? For instance, if its 3.5 rating, it will display the 3.5 stars and the rest of the stars empty. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: @amir, yes you can. you will need to add another loop. To calculate that index, you need to use this code - $emptyStarStart = floor($rating['average_rate'] + 0.5); and loop like for( $emptyStarStart; $emptyStarStart<5; $emptyStarStart++ ) {... or something similar.

Comment: @amir, if this is now working for you, please accept the answer.